# Delete data frame but still lose memory

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I have two large data frames called df0 (120 million obs) and df1 (50 million obs). They have the same 44 variables (as columns). I need to append the data so that the new data frame has 120+50 = 170 million observations and 44 columns.

I use:

```
frames = [df0, df1]
df = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)

or
df = df0.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
```

They work just fine. But when I delete df0 and df1 using

```
del df0
del df1
```

the system does not release the memory. I've read on stackoverflow that this is typical for python/other languages. However, I run into memory issues after this and python does not release this memory.

Any suggestions on how to avoid having so much memory eaten up?

SOLVED:
As juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out, a surviving reference will mean the data frame will not be deleted. Once I deleted all references to the data frame, the memory is freed up once the data frame is deleted.

Comment: how are you deleting it?

Comment: using del df0 and del df1. sorry forgot to specify.

Comment: Your `frames` list still has references to the dataframes. If any other references survive to those data-frames, or to that list for that matter, then those data-frames will survive until their reference count reaches 0.

Comment: Fundamentally, these problems should be avoided if you follow clean-coding practices. Avoid plopping these objects into the global scope - pass arguments into functions, these functions will use local variables, and the references will automatically get deleted when the function terminates so you don't worry about rogue references everywhere, and then return data that you need. If you code cleanly this should be handled automatically for you by the Python runtime.

Comment: Also, if you are working in an IPython session, or a Jupyter Notebook, watch out! Every time you simply do `df1` or `df.head()` to look at your data-frame, the IPython session keeps a reference in it's rather expansive history. Honestly, this probably should be closed as a duplicate of the many questions on Python memory management.

Comment: Ok this is helpful since I did use commands such as df1 and df1.head()

Comment: Thanks  juanpa.arrivillaga, you were correct. It was a surviving reference that led to the data frames surviving. I removed them and am now good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import gc
del df0
del df1 
gc.collect()
```

the reason is when you delelte df0 and df1,the program only delete the reference to the data in memory.When you do gc.collect(),it checks those data in memory that has not been used and remove them.

Comment: I had tried this but it didn't release the memory. I guess it might be being used since I used commands such as df1 and df1.head()